# Need C# equivalent for the below SQL HashBytes function

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, hashbytes

I have created hash value using below function in sql

SQL query

```
Select hashbytes('MD5', PNumber+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),cast(datestamp as  binary),1))   
From dbo.Events
```

Now I need to get the equivalent C# function in order to get the hash value and pass it to a stored procedure.

I am using below code to get the c# equivalent. But values are not matching

C# Code

```
var strDate = policyEventFromQueue.DateStamp.ToString();
var binaryvalue = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strDate);
var hashkey = GetMD5Hash(PNumber + binaryvalue);

public static byte[] GetMD5Hash(string input)
{
    System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider x = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input);

    bs = x.ComputeHash(bs);
    return bs;
}
```

Here are test results:

From SQL Server:

```
PNumber ='4272535529'
DateStamp ='2016-06-30 12:19:35.257961'

HashValue : 0x104E09499B76CB59420AEEEDBBE187F8
```

In C# I am getting the value from DB Field value as below

```
[0]: 16
[1]: 78
[2]: 9
[3]: 73
[4]: 155
[5]: 118
[6]: 203
[7]: 89
[8]: 66
[9]: 10
[10]: 238
[11]: 237
[12]: 187
[13]: 225
[14]: 135
[15]: 248
```

From C# GetMD5Hash Function i am getting value as below

```
[0]: 30
[1]: 153
[2]: 105
[3]: 203
[4]: 34
[5]: 124
[6]: 20
[7]: 12
[8]: 207
[9]: 113
[10]: 210
[11]: 144
[12]: 18
[13]: 145
[14]: 22
[15]: 36
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Start by getting the same date value before it is being hashed.

Comment: Are you sure the hashing function isn't working the same, or is the string you're hashing different? What exactly does `PNumber+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),cast(datestamp as  binary),1)` look like in SQL compared to `PNumber + Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strDate)`?

Comment: What is the type of datestamp? Is it a string?

Comment: Use BitConverter.ToString(bs); then replace all "-" with empty string.

Comment: i have edited my question with test result

Comment: datestamp is Datetime2 filed in DB.  In C# it is Datetime?   type

Comment: What is the value of datestamp?  Is it '2016-06-30 12:19:35.257961'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In c# it looks like the format for a DateTime ToString() is more like this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString()
//--------
"8/3/2016 4:11:14 PM"
```

I think you're hashing two different strings.  For the hashes to match you'll need to format the dates the same before computing the hash value.

Also it looks like on sql server you're hashing something like:

```
select '12313135' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),cast(sysdatetime() as  binary),1)
//------------
123131350x077B7127E688B23B0B000000000000000000000000000000
```

Another issue could be this:

```
var binaryvalue = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToString());
var hashkey = "123456" + binaryvalue;
Console.WriteLine(hashkey)
//----------
123456System.Byte[]
```

your conversions between strings and bytes is off.

Comment: I found the issue . But i don't know the solution. Problem is with the sql datetime column. It is taking different format. I have posted a separate question for this. Please have a look at that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761149/hashbytes-computed-column-cannot-be-persisted-because-the-column-is-non-determin